# Hilighting parent item while hovering child item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have menu with 2 submenus. Using jQuery I want to higlight hovered item. I can't solve how to higlight parent item, when cursor is on the child item. For hovering I used class caled active:

```
.vertical-active {
background:#0F6;
}
```

Jquery function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('.submenu a').hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass('vertical-active');
    $(this).parent('vertical-links a').addClass('vertical-active');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('vertical-active');
        $(this).parent('vertical-links a').removeClass('vertical-active');
    });
});
```

Problem is in parent selector, but I don't know how to select submenu's parent item.

**JSFiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tZ/4/**

Comment: what exactly you want to highlight?? should it be ul with class `submenu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in addition to [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/6g9tZ/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".vertical-links > li > a").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('vertical-active');
    });    

    $('.submenu a').on("mouseenter mouseleave",function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('vertical-active');
        $(this).closest("ul").siblings("a").toggleClass('vertical-active');
    });    
});
```

Comment: Can you add code for highlighting parent item when hovered?

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submenu a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).add($(this).closest('ul').closest('li').children('a')).toggleClass('vertical-active');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tZ/5/)

**EDIT:**

to highlight the parent as well, you'd do

```
$('.vertical-links > li > a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('vertical-active')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tZ/12/)

Comment: Can you add code for highlighting parent item when hovered?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the relevant parts of your code with:

```
$(this).parents('li:eq(1)').find("> a").addClass('vertical-active');
....
$(this).parents('li:eq(1)').find("> a").removeClass('vertical-active');
```

One problem with your code is that you were looking for a "parent `<a>`", but there is no such thing; the `<a>` is a child of your parent. So here we search for a parent `<li>`, not the immediate, but actually the grandparent, find its direct `<a>` child and highlight it.

Additionally you had `parent('vertical-links')` which should be `parent('.vertical-links')` (not the dot:  its a class not an element).